# Problem updating custom built progressCircle in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have built a custom progress bar and the code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';



class ProgressCircle extends Component {

    styles = {
        svg: {
            width: `${this.props.size}`,
            height: `${this.props.size}`
        },
        zero: {
            cx: '50',
          cy: '50',
          r: '32',
          fill: `${this.props.unfilledColor}`
        },
        one: {
            cx: '50',
            cy: '50',
            r: '16',
            stroke: `${this.props.primaryColors[0]}`,
            strokeWidth: '32',
            strokeDasharray: `${this.props.percent} 100`,
            transform: 'rotate(-90deg)',
            transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
        },
          two: {
            cx: '50',
            cy: '50',
            r: '16',
            stroke: `${this.props.primaryColors[1]}`,
            strokeWidth: '32',
            strokeDasharray: `${this.props.percent - 25} 100`,
            fill: 'none'

          },

          three: {
            cx: '50',
            cy: '50',
            r: '16',
            stroke: `${this.props.primaryColors[2]}`,
            strokeWidth: '32',
            strokeDasharray: `${this.props.percent - 50} 100`,
            transform: 'rotate(90deg)',
            transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
            fill: 'none'
          },

          four: {
            cx: '50',
            cy: '50',
            r: '16',
            stroke: `${this.props.primaryColors[3]}`,
            strokeWidth: '32',
            strokeDasharray: `${this.props.percent - 75} 100`,
            transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
            transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
            fill: 'none'
          },
          fill: {
            cx: '50',
            cy: '50',
            r: '25',
            fill: `${this.props.fill}`

          }
    }
    render(){
         {
            if (this.props.percent >= 0 && this.props.percent <= 25){
                return (
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style = {this.styles.svg}>
                        <circle  style={this.styles.zero}/>
                        <circle  style={this.styles.one} />
                        <circle  style={this.styles.fill}/>
                    </svg>
                );

            } else if(this.props.percent > 25 && this.props.percent <= 50) {
                return(
                <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style = {this.styles.svg}>
                        <circle  style={this.styles.zero}/>
                        <circle  style={this.styles.one} />
                        <circle style={this.styles.two} />
                        <circle  style={this.styles.fill}/> 
                    </svg>
                );
            } else if(this.props.percent > 50 && this.props.percent <= 75) {
                return(
                <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style = {this.styles.svg}>
                        <circle  style={this.styles.zero}/>
                        <circle  style={this.styles.one} />
                        <circle  style={this.styles.two} />
                        <circle  style={this.styles.three}/> 
                        <circle  style={this.styles.fill}/>
                    </svg>
                );
            } else if(this.props.percent > 75 && this.props.percent <= 100) {
                return(
                <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style = {this.styles.svg}>
                        <circle style={this.styles.zero}/>
                        <circle  style={this.styles.one} />
                        <circle  style={this.styles.two} />
                        <circle  style={this.styles.three}/> 
                        <circle  style={this.styles.four} /> 
                        <circle  style={this.styles.fill}/>
                    </svg>
                );
            } 
         }









    }
}




export default ProgressCircle;
```

Now I have simple App component from where I call ProgressCircle component when I manually change the percent value everything works fine however If create a count state and add it to the progressCircle I get funny result. Here is the snapshot & code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ProgressCircle from './ProgressCircle';



export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count: 90
        }

    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        if(event.target.value >= 0 && event.target.value <= 100) {
            this.setState({
                count : event.target.value
            })
        }

    }




    render(){


        return (
            <div>
            <ProgressCircle percent = {this.state.count} 
            primaryColors = {['pink', 'magenta','green', 'yellow']}
            fill = "white" 
            unfilledColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
            size = "500px" />

            <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" onChange={this.handleChange} value = {this.state.count} />
           {console.log(this.state.count)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Let me add screenshot:

[image]

The above screenshot is when initial value given to count(percent) value. I have added input for adding any value however if I add number between 0 and 100 the progressCircle shows only one color why is that?
Here is codepen link you can try it out : https://codepen.io/sriramhegdeofficial/pen/KKwqQQQ

Comment: I don't understand your problem since I'm seeing multiple colors once you change the input. Check this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-moser-m24io

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working, [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-dust-6hwc7). The only thing i changed was the input type, but it still works with `type="text"`...